# Chapterbib Bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, chapterbib

I am creating a template for my PhD thesis and I am trying to use `chapterbib` to have two different bibliographies for each chapter. I run compile from the main file, then the Bibliography  in each of the two .aux files and then compile from the main file again. The .bib file is in the same subfolder where I have the single chapters. However, I can't seem to make it work. Any chance you can spot where I am wrong?

Thanks a lot.

The main file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{newclude}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
...
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\chapter*{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\include*{chapters/abstract}

\chapter{Introduction}
\include*{chapters/introduction}

\chapter{First paper}
\include*{chapters/chapter02}

\chapter{Second paper}
\include*{chapters/chapter03}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\include*{chapters/conclusion}

\end{document}
```

and chapter02.tex and chapter03.tex are, respectively:

```
\section{Introduction}
Here the introduction of the first paper. Example of reference is \cite{blanchard_labor_2010}. 

\bibliography{BiblioC1} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

```
\section{Introduction}
Here the introduction of the second paper. Example of reference is \cite{calvo_staggered_1983}. 

\bibliography{BiblioC1} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
```

The .bib file, which is included in the folder containing chapter02.tex and chapter03.tex includes the two citations.

Comment: untested but my first try would be to remove this newclude package. And you should put the \chapter command inside the \include.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I remove \chapter the bibliographies work but now chapters are not numbered anymore (e.g. sections of chapter two are 0.1,0.2,0.3 and sections of chapter three are 0.4,0.5,0.6). How can I use the \chapter command inside \include?

`\include{chapters/introduction}
\include{chapters/chapter02}
\include{chapters/chapter03}
\include{chapters/conclusion}`

Comment: I did  not wrote that you should remove chapter.

Comment: Remove the line `\usepackage{newclude}`, and replace all occurrences of `\include*` by `\include`, then it works. The package `newclude` is not compatible with `chapterbib`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, I am now trying to modify the document and for some reasons, although the bibliographies show up, I am not able to add new citations (e.g. if inside the chapters I give the command \cite the system does not recognize any item of the bibliography). Do you have any idea of why? thanks a lot